# How to register a new message processor class with WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

How do you register a new message processor class with WSO2 ESB?

I've tried dropping the jar file into CARBON_HOME/repository/components/plugins and dropins but when I create a custom MP via the carbon console I get a ClassNotFound exception.

I am using version 4.0.3.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In older releases you needed to add it in axis2.xml. In the sections Message Receivers, Message Formatters and/or Message Builders.
Maybe now you can create an OSGi bundle to add it, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is osgi bundle keep the jar at repository/components/dropins folder..
Else if it is a normal jar keep at repository/components/lib folder..
If you keep at plugins folder(If it is an OSGi bundle) you need to edit the bundle.info file

Answer (score 0):

In version 4.0.3 put the jar into repository/components/lib folder. You have to restart ESB

Answer (score 0):

Jar file needs to be copied in CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib folder 
during the server start up this jar file will be picked up.